# Laravel - Javascript CSS styling doesn't get applied even though code works in console

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

from highlights.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    setAllDifferentHeight();
    highlight();
} 
); 

function highlight()
{

    var firsts = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
    for(var i=0; i<firsts.length; i++){
        firsts[i].style.backgroundColor = "gold";
    }
    var seconds = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
    for(var i=0; i<seconds.length; i++){
        seconds[i].style.backgroundColor = "silver";
    }
    var thirds = document.getElementsByClassName("third");
    for(var i=0; i<thirds.length; i++){
        thirds[i].style.backgroundColor = "brown";
    }
    var lasts = document.getElementsByClassName("last");
    for (var i = lasts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        lasts[i].style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    }

}
```

from index.blade.php:

```
        @foreach($student as $s)
        <?php $sum = $s->mc+$s->tc+$s->hw+$s->bs+$s->ks+$s->ac; ?>

        @if($sum == $first)
        <tr class = "first">
        @elseif($sum == $second)
        <tr class = "second">                   
        @elseif($sum == $third)
        <tr class = "third">                    
        @elseif($sum == $last)
        <tr class = "last">                 
        @endif
```

The HTML is generated with the right classes in the right places, but no highlighting is done by the javascript. When I run the Javascript code in the console, it does what I want it to. What is the issue here?

Comment: Why don't you define the background color in the CSS class (`.first { background-color: gold } ...`) ?

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Doing what you're doing should work, so we need more information.